# mainlistview1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am following a tutorial on making list views, but I cannot find the cause of the error

> mainlistview1 cannot be resolved or is not a field.

**Here is my current code:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.AdapterView.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    String[] riverCities = new String[] {"Greenville", "Vicksburg",
            "Memphis", "Natchez", "Cape Girardeau", "Helena"};   
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainListView1);
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.id.mainListView1, riverCities);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

**The layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**problem:**

```
 android.R.id.mainListView1
```

The `mainListView1` is not located in the android default layout id thus the compiler cannot find it.

**solution:**

Change it to the default list view item id

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this ,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, riverCities);
```